# Trouble writing likelihood

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

I'm having trouble writing the likelihood for a homework question:

Suppose $X=Z(Y+\theta)+(1-Z)(\theta-Y)$ and $X_1, X_2, X_3 \overset{iid}{\sim} f_X(x)$ where $Z\sim \rm{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ and $Y\sim \rm{exponential}(1)$ and $Z$ and $Y$ are independent. Let $x=(7.2, 9.3, 8.6)$ be the observed data.

Can you guys help me (give hints, ideas) on how to write the likelihood (or log-likelhood function)?

So far I have:
$L(\theta;x) = f_X(x|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^3 f_X(x|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^3 f_Z(??|\theta)f_Y(???|\theta)$ but I can't figure out what to do really in this strange situation.

Comment: Note that Z is not a function of $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand the formula for $X$ out, you should get $X-\theta = Y(2Z-1)$. Now $2Z-1$ is a 50-50 chance of a +1 and a -1 respectively. Which means $Y(2Z-1)$ is exponential with a random sign attached - a [Laplace, or *double exponential*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) distribution, with mean zero and scale 1.

(You should be able to make a more formal argument there, though.)

So $X$ is a location family based of that - the same double-exponential thing shifted by $\theta$ (i.e. still with scale 1).

Can you do it now?

Comment: It makes "sense" although I'm not sure how to formally show that $X\sim \rm{laplace}$. But assuming that is true, yes I can finish the problem :) thanks

Comment: Given $W$ takes the values ${-1,+1}$ with equal probability, and $Y$ is standard exponential, you just need to show what the distribution of $WY$ is. Which is the same as $X$ being equally likely to take the values $Y$ or $-Y$. Would reading about [mixtures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) help (especially, say the first two equations [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution))? Though you should probably be able to manage from just basic principles.